# Why did my soldering iron tip turn blue?

Tags: soldering

I tinned the iron and removed the solder after it but as I removed it suddenly turned strangely blue. It is a brand new soldering iron tip rated perfectly for 60 watts.  While tinning I noticed some flux boiling in one corner developing black layer beneath it.[image][image: when i tried to clean it with metal sponge it seems to remove a layer of oxide maybe and this make the tip uneven]
But the tips functions and heat normally

Comment: Can we see a picture?

Comment: It is oxide.  Whether it's tin oxide, lead oxide, copper oxide or iron oxide -- I don't know.  But iron tips that have clean solder on them tend to do that.

Comment: So is that a problem i have to watch out for or thats normal

Comment: @Jyotir That's normal. Just make sure you clean/tin your tip before using it. It also doesn't hurt to re-tin and then lightly clean the tip (on a metal sponge) after use.

Comment: That's normal. You can't expect any common metal to maintain it's bright and shiny mirror polish when it's hot in an atmosphere containing oxygen. Try to avoid it being jet black for too long though if you can.

Comment: I added a picture@DKNguyen @CalebReister

Comment: @Jyotir Getting some [tip tinner](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00NS4J6BY/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_rokMDbCY2ERFK) may help.